# htaccess file to redirect /stringa to /index.php?action=stringb

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess` file and I need to redirect `/stringa` to `/index.php?action=stringb`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /app/
   RewriteRule ^model/(.*)$ /app/index.php [R=301,NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^view/(.*)$ /app/index.php [R=301,NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^util/(.*)$ /app/index.php [R=301,NC,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^stringa$ /app/index.php?action=stringb [L,R=301]
   RewriteRule ^ /app/index.php [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what exactly are you asking? Seems like you have a solution already in place. If not, what is your precise problem? Please see also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry, this line still not working for me "   RewriteRule ^stringa$ /app/index.php?action=stringb [L,R=301]"

Comment: You still need to say exactly what does not work. What happens when you try the URL?